Bash echoes all itterations from for-loop into first value. Then continues normally
This is my first time posting anything here, so if I forget something or you need more info to answer my question, please let me know.
So I am trying to make a small bash script, that echoes all files in a folder into an array using a for-loop.
The snippet looks like this:
romList=(*)

for line in *
do
    romList+="($(echo "$line\n"))"
done

Then when I try to echo out each value with this code:
for entry in "${romList[@]}"
do
    echo $entry
done


I get a result that looks like this:
$ file1 file2 file3
file2
file3

So for the first iteration it puts all of the files found into the first value and then continues as expected for the subsequent iterations.
For context I am trying to cleanup my roms folders, by removing language descriptions in the individual filenames. So my plan was to echo the filename into an array as a string, check up against an array of patterns and then remove that pattern from the string, so I can use it as a new filename.
That also means that the filenames have spaces and parenthesis in them, but I don't understand if that should affect only the first iteration.
If you have another (read better) solution for achieving that, also please let me know.

add typeset -p romList before and after the 1st for loop to see the contents of the array

please update the question with 5-6 sample file names (includingsome filenames have spaces and parenthesis) and the expected contents of the array

[tag:bash] - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

To add a new element to an array, you need to parenthesise the right hand side.
romList+=("($(echo "$line\n"))")

Without it, it's interpreted as string concatenation and it operates on the first element of the array.
But if there's a file foo.txt, it already gets into the array in the first assignment (romList=(*)), why do you need (foo.txt\n) in the array, as well?

Thanks!
Adding the extra parenthesis solved the problem. Removing "\n" from the loop and the "*" from the initial variable cleaned up the array - "/n" just added /n as plain text in the end of each value after adding the parenthesis and the * resulted in the array having two copies of the array inside itself for some reason.

@anistorian: "for some reason" - because the asterisk gets expanded by the shell to the list of all matching files.

@anistorian to be clear, you shouldn't be using echo either, its doing nothing useful. You should just be doing romList+=( "$line" ). Make sure to copy/paste all of your shell scripts into http://shellcheck.net until you get familiar with shell as the code in your question has other issues that shellcheck can help you with.
